# Input pula linha, como não pular em Python?

Tags: python

Como utilizar o input e impedir que ele pule uma linha antes do próximo, em Python? 
por exemplo:

```
Digite N: 1
Digite dígito para A: 5
Digite dígito para E: 9
Digite x: 8.25
Digite y: 7.3
Errou
Código: 9
```

meu código retorna isso:

```
Digite N: 1

Digite dígito para A: 5

Digite dígito para E: 9

Digite x: 8.25

Digite y: 7.3
    Errou
Código:  9
```

Comment: Como assim? O usuário não teria que apertar Enter para confirmar a entrada? isso já pularia uma linha

Comment: boa, isso mesmo. e como impedir que pule?

Comment: O input() não pula linha. Ele vai descer pra linha de baixo quando o usuário pressionar `enter`. O resultado fica igual você colocou na pergunta.

Comment: showw, valeu mano!!!!

Comment: então @nosklo , editei a pergunta, agora ficou cloro a diferença

Comment: @TiagoRassesRas sim agora entendi a diferença, porém, não dá pra saber como você conseguiu esse segundo resultado, sem ver o seu código. Eu fiz aqui e ficou igual você queria; Não está pulando linha nenhuma aqui.

Comment: Tiago, por favor, edite sua pergunta e adicione o seu código. Somente com a saída não há como aferir o que está errado.

Comment: Já melhorou muito com sua edição, mas falta o [mcve] com o problema para a comunidade identificar o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Não acho que é possível. Mas uma alternativa seria fazer assim:

```
entrada = input()
x, y = entrada.split()
```

ou

```
entrada = input().split()
x = entrada[0]
y = entrada[1]
```

lembrando que split() só pode ser usado em strings então se você precisa que os valores sejam int, por exemplo, é só converter, assim:

```
x = int(entrada[0])
```

Comment: obrigado, mas não posso utilizar métodos

Comment: Olha, eu acho que o input() sempre vai pular linha, mas se você descobrir como fazer, avisa aí.

Comment: ok. tks. qualquer coisa aviso sim

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar pular linhas, **não é preciso fazer nada** - o `input()` **já não pula** linhas como você mostrou na sua pergunta.

Deve haver alguma **outra coisa errada** no seu código, que está causando esse pulo de linhas, pois esse não é o comportamento normal da função `input()` do python.

Comment: Eu diria que é algo como... `print(input('Bazinga?'))`

Comment: `bola_de_cristal(input('Sem código?'))`

Answer (score 0):

Olha sua pergunta não ficou muito clara pra mim ainda, mas pelo que entendi tu quer isso.

```
linha = ''
inseridos = []

while True:
    if linha != 'ABC': 
        linha = input("Insira string\n")
        inseridos.append(linha)
    else:
        print(inseridos)
        break
```

Código para ao se inserir 'ABC', e o resultado é uma lista, que você pode tratar facilmente.

Comment: então, a questão é simples, ele pede N e pula uma linha antes de pedir o A e pula outra antes de pedir o E ... etc.  eu quero que ele não pule essa linha como no exemplo acima